# Get item from bs4.element.Tag

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have element with type bs4.element.Tag

```
<a class="nav-link match-link-stats" href="/football/matches/match867851_Kalteng_Putra-Arema-online/" title="Stat"><i class="icon-match-link"></i></a>
```

And I want to get "/football/matches/match867851_Kalteng_Putra-Arema-online/" from this element. How to do it?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This answer assumes you already have the `Tag` element as an object.  If not, use KunduK's answer.

---

You can use `tag.get('href')` or `tag['href']`:

```
>>> tag.get('href')
'/football/matches/match867851_Kalteng_Putra-Arema-online/'
>>> tag['href']
'/football/matches/match867851_Kalteng_Putra-Arema-online/'
```

The difference is that `tag.get('href')` will return None if the attribute doesn't exist, while `tag['href']` will raise a `KeyError` in that case.  That's the same behavior as in a `dict`.

Full example:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup('<a class="nav-link match-link-stats" href="/football/matches/match867851_Kalteng_Putra-Arema-online/" title="Stat"><i class="icon-match-link"></i></a>')
>>> tag = soup.find('a')
>>> type(tag)
<class 'bs4.element.Tag'>
>>> tag.get('href')
'/football/matches/match867851_Kalteng_Putra-Arema-online/'
>>> tag['href']
'/football/matches/match867851_Kalteng_Putra-Arema-online/'
```

Answer (score 12):

```
tag.findChild("a")['href']
```

You grab the "a" tag, then take the "href" attribute

Comment: Also the old non-conventional names shouldn't be used any more – `findChild()` is called just `find()` now.

Answer (score 5):

Use css selecor and get the attribute `href`

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data='''<a class="nav-link match-link-stats" href="/football/matches/match867851_Kalteng_Putra-Arema-online/" title="Stat"><i class="icon-match-link"></i></a>'''

soup= BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')
print(soup.select_one('.match-link-stats')['href'])
```

Output:

```
/football/matches/match867851_Kalteng_Putra-Arema-online/
```